# How to prevent class instanciation from outside but keep it usable?

Tags: c#, factory, .net-assembly

I've written a class for an assembly that should only be instanciated by a factory inside this assembly.

Outside Assembly:

```
MyClass myClass = factoryInstance.GetInstanceOfMyClass();
```

It should be forbidden to instanciate this class outside

Forbidden:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
```

I've seen some complicated approaches. Is there a simple way I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way should be to make the constructor `internal`:

```
public class MyClass
{
    internal MyClass()
    {
    }
}
```

As long as your factory method is located in the same assembly it will be able to create instances of your class, but any code outside of the assembly will not be able to do that.

Comment: Damnit, I hate it when "1 new answer has been posted" pops up xD +1

Answer (score 2):

Just make the visibility of the constructor **internal** so that no other classes outside the assembly it is contained within can see it.

**Assembly 1**

```
public class MyClass
{
  internal MyClass()
  {
    // ... code here ...
  }
}

public class MyFactory
{
  public MyClass GetInstanceOfMyClass()
  {
    return new MyClass();
  }
}
```

**Assembly 2**

```
// Invalid
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();

// Valid
MyClass myClass = myFactoryInstance.GetInstanceOfMyClass();
```

Then you can instantiate this class within the assembly (via your factory) but it cannot be instantiated outside of the assembly.